# Solrnet & Clustering

Tags: solr, solrnet

Is it possible to get clustering in Solr querying via SolrNet? 
using built-in algos. like Carrot2 etc.? Can anyone share some sample code or tips to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, [Solr clustering](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent) is not currently implemented in SolrNet. It doesn't seem to be hard to implement though. Here's an outline of what it would take:

- Model the Solr response for clusters as a class (e.g. `ClusteringResult`). For example, [StatsResult](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/StatsResult.cs) models the response for the StatsComponent.
- Add a property for `ClusteringResult` in `ISolrQueryResults<T>` and `SolrQueryResults<T>`
- Implement a `ISolrResponseParser<T>` to parse the part of Solr XML response with the clustering information and load a `ClusteringResult` object. See [other response parsers](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/SolrNet/Impl/ResponseParsers/) for reference.
- Register the response parser in the [built-in container](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Startup.cs), the [Ninject module](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Ninject.Integration.SolrNet/SolrNetModule.cs), the [Windsor facility](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration/SolrNetFacility.cs) and the [StructureMap registry](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/StructureMap.SolrNetIntegration/SolrNetRegistry.cs).
- Model the parameters involved in the query as a class (e.g. `ClusteringParameters`). This would include a property to mirror carrot.algorithm, another for carrot.url, etc.
- Add a property for `ClusteringParameters` in [`QueryOptions`](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Commands/Parameters/QueryOptions.cs).
- Serialize this `ClusteringParameters` to querystring parameters in [`SolrQueryExecuter`](http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Impl/SolrQueryExecuter.cs).

And of course, **unit tests** for everything. Ideally, also an integration test.

Then send me a pull request ;-)

Comment: just registered an enhancement request about this: http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=121

Comment: Thanks much. Will try and help where I can and add my 2c to your excellent effort.